# How to interpret a statement having "if anything" in it

Tags: sentence-meaning, comprehension

> The excavation also tells the story of the 7 stages of the civilization, from development to maturity to decay, the last of which hints at a strange piece of history, with more questions than answers. After the peak of the civilization Dholavira was temporarily abandoned, after which it seems that the settlers returned with a markedly de-urbanized culture. There are hints that they willingly chose to simplify their lives, rather than try to ride the collapse of their once glorified civilization. *Here, on the ruins, you will have a chance to contemplate what progress and civilization mean and what, **if anything**, is truly permanent.*

This is a paragraph from the article "https://www.gujarattourism.com/kutch-zone/kutch/dholavira.html"

What does "if anything" mean here , or like generally how should I read it as.  I tried searching online on some dictionaries but not getting any satisfactory explanation.

Comment: 'and what, if anything, is truly permanent' = 'and what is truly permanent ... if there is anything that _is_ [truly permanent].'

Comment: When ***if anything*** appears after ***what***, it's normally just the writer "hedging his bets" in case there are in fact ***no members in the set of things referenced by "what"***. Which may sometimes amount to the writer actually ***suggesting*** that "what" might actually refer to ***nothing at all***. It's exactly the same with, say, *Tell us **who, if anyone**, you want to marry,* or *He doesn't know **where** he wants to live, **if anywhere*** (perhaps implying he's suicidal, and doesn't want to live *anywhere*, but often that might just imply he's got no special preference).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, could you please write an answer for this question, it's a bit hard for me to decipher from the comment itself of what exactly you are trying to explain with those "..." And "[truly permanent] statement"

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for the explanation , can you show me how to apply your explanation in understanding the same line from the paragraph which I have posted in question.  How shall I apply the special preference dimension in here

Comment: 'Here, on the ruins, you will have a chance to contemplate what progress and civilization mean and what, if anything, is truly permanent.' = 'Here, on the ruins, you will have a chance to contemplate what progress and civilization mean, and what is truly permanent ... if there is anything that _is_ [truly permanent]..'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase, "if anything", gives the option of choosing nothing.

> Tell me what we should do, if anything

This can be reworded: "*Tell me what we should do, unless we shouldn't do anything, in which case, don't tell me what we should do.*"

So your sentence can be reworded:

> *Here, on the ruins, you will have a chance to contemplate what progress and civilization mean and what is truly permanent, **including the possibility that nothing is truly permanent***.

Comment: Thank you so much @gotube :) , so basically all options are option to choose including none of the option .... thanks again for the answer

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "if anything" emphasizes there is some likelihood that *nothing* is truly permanent.  Without the words "if anything", writing "contemplate what is truly permanent" would suggest (though not strictly demand) that there must be *something* that is truly permanent.

To restate:

- "...contemplate what, if anything, is truly X" means that there may be a few things or perhaps nothing that is truly X;
- "...contemplate what is truly X" means that there are probably a few things that are truly X.

In both cases, the writer is suggesting that such conclusions may be difficult to determine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Iam still confused of whether the author wants to convey that there is something which is permanent or not ?

Comment: @Fin27: What is it you don't understand about Patrick's answer here? Your cited author ***did*** include "if anything" - so as Patrick says, he's explicitly making the point that it's at least *possible* nothing is permanent. His other option would have been ***not*** to include "if anything", which would normally be understood as implying there must be something that is permanent. In such contexts, unqualified ***what*** always implies "something", just as ***Who** is Mr XXX?* implies there must be *someone* called Mr XXX.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am not a native English speaker, I am not understanding if the author does not include "if anything" what is meant by "Contemplate what is truly permanent"... I understand the meaning of contemplate that is to think about something, but cannot understand in the context of Patrick or your answer, it would be really helpful if you can explain it in an answer please

Comment: To restate: "...contemplate what, if anything, is truly X" means that there may be a few things or perhaps nothing that is truly X; "...contemplate what is truly X" means that there are probably a few things that are truly X.  I've edited the answer thus.

Comment: Thank you so much @PatrickSzalapski , the last explanation makes it a lot clearer :)